# React native Promise rejection. Network request failed (How to fetch data)

Tags: mysql, database, fetch, react-native

i try to get my data with mysql on my React Native application.

I made these installations :

npm install express --save
npm install body-parser --save
npm install mysql --save

This is the code of my server :

[Connexion.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bztVa.png)

If i go to : http://localhost:3308/user , i can see my data.

I want execute a request there :

[Routes.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4kcb.png)

I saw this exemple :

```
test(){
fetch('http://yourPCip:3000/users')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(users => console.warn(users))
```

}

What I want to do :

> 1 - Connexion in the file connexion.js

[Space]

> 2- Query and fetch in my file router.js
>   Line 17 in the file router.js , i want a request like that:
>   -Query
>   -Fetch

I want the query IN This file and after the fetch ,to do multiple checks

I have some question :

> - How to find my PCip? It is the IPv4 address of my Ethernet?

[Space]

> -I have to run: node connexion.js to run my request . I would know how to make a request without having to run the command line server?

Can i have an exemple that looks like my problem ?

Thank you!